# Is there a way to do background tasks with react native expo with my example?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, background-process

Is there a way to do background tasks with react native expo as my example?
I just want to make post method  every 5 seconds and also console.log it to see if its work 
this example:

[this the site of the example](https://medium.com/@inkdrop/a-simple-way-to-run-js-in-background-thread-on-react-native-8fff345576da)

I want to change this example and I want to try to use it for my needs, so how I make post method every 5 seconds and also console.log
in the background?

```
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

const FETCH_TASKNAME = 'test_task'
const INTERVAL = 60

function test() {
    console.log('function is running')
}

export async function registerFetchTask() {
    TaskManager.defineTask(FETCH_TASKNAME, test);

    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    switch (status) {
        case BackgroundFetch.Status.Restricted:
        case BackgroundFetch.Status.Denied:
            console.log("Background execution is disabled");
            return;

        default: {
            console.debug("Background execution allowed");

            let tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
            if (tasks.find(f => f.taskName === FETCH_TASKNAME) == null) {
                console.log("Registering task");
                await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(FETCH_TASKNAME);

                tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
                console.debug("Registered tasks", tasks);
            } else {
                console.log(`Task ${FETCH_TASKNAME} already registered, skipping`);
            }

            console.log("Setting interval to", INTERVAL);
            await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(INTERVAL);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [expo-background-fetch](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/) library. It's exactly what you need in expo.

```
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

TaskManager.defineTask(YOUR_TASK_NAME, () => {
  try {
    const receivedNewData = // do your background fetch here
    return receivedNewData ? BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData : BackgroundFetch.Result.NoData;
  } catch (error) {
    return BackgroundFetch.Result.Failed;
  }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: can you show me on snack-expo how to do console.log every 10 min with your example?

Comment: i guess i cant show on expo snakc, you have to check on any manual deb=vice

Comment: I will do it on a real device, just show me how to write it.

Comment: please read the docs, as i havent implemnted that. But its possible

Comment: I read already and try many things and it doesn't work for me.
look at my example above, I change it that you will see and help me.